# Same css for multiple combinations of class selector not working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

When I try to apply simple CSS for some divs based on css class selectors where different combination of selectors have the same css style, it is not getting applied. If I write this css separately for each selector combination then it is working. I cannot understand why it is getting failed. If my CSS selector works then **"Left DIV | Left Score"** should go to right side.

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/wf2y7m01/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

div.team-info.team-pre-info.lpanel.Soccer 
div.team-info.team-final-in-info.lpanel.Soccer 
div.score-box.score-box-home.Soccer {
    float:right;
}

div.team-info.team-pre-info.rpanel.Soccer
div.team-info.team-final-in-info.rpanel.Soccer
div.score-box.score-box-away.Soccer {
    float:left;
} 

</style> 
</head>
<body>

<div style="color:#0000FF;width:500px">

  <div class="team-info team-pre-info lpanel Soccer" style="display:inline;">
      Left DIV 
    <div style="display:inline;"> | Left Score</div>
  </div>


 <div style="display:inline;">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Middle DIV&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  </div>



<div class="team-info team-pre-info rpanel Soccer"  style="display:inline;">
<div style="display:inline;"> Right Score |</div>
      Right DIV 

  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to separate selectors by comma (https://jsfiddle.net/dsp4w224/):

```
    div.team-info.team-pre-info.lpanel.Soccer, 
div.team-info.team-final-in-info.lpanel.Soccer, 
div.score-box.score-box-home.Soccer {
    float:right;
}

div.team-info.team-pre-info.rpanel.Soccer,
div.team-info.team-final-in-info.rpanel.Soccer,
div.score-box.score-box-away.Soccer {
    float:left;
}
```

More information: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_comma.asp

Answer (score 0):

Individual selectors should be comma separated, not space separated. The space character in CSS selectors is actually the [descendant selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors) meaning that the following selector:

```
div.team-info.team-pre-info.lpanel.Soccer div.team-info.team-final-in-info.lpanel.Soccer div.score-box.score-box-home.Soccer
```

is looking for a `div` with the classes `.score-box`, `.score-box-home` & `.Soccer` that is a (grand)child of another `div` with the classes `.team-info`, `.team-final-in-info`, `.lpanel` & `.Soccer which is itself a (grand)child of a`div`with the classes`.team-info`,`.team-pre-info`,`.lpanel`&`.Soccer`.